# Trigger javascript function with anchor from another page

Tags: javascript, triggers, anchor

Is there a way to trigger `<a href="javascript:switch_tabs('tab3');">` with an anchor link like this `<a href="www.sample.com/page.html#reference" class="links">`from another page?

Did something like

if(window.location.hash == '#abstract'){
$(document).ready(function() {
  switch_tabs('tab1');
}); 
}
if(window.location.hash == '#full'){
$(document).ready(function() {
  switch_tabs('tab2');
}); 
}
if(window.location.hash == '#reference'){
$(document).ready(function() {
  switch_tabs('tab3');
}); 
}

If someone wants to make it prettier, be my guest.

Thanks

Comment: only if there is a script in page.html to capture the location.hash and trigger it for you

Comment: Thanks managed to do something with location.hash, apreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to get the script.